# Se for possível, como posso trabalhar com valores inteiro com 1 milhão de dígitos ou mais em python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estou executando alguns experimentos com números primos e precisava processar números inteiros enormes, porém ao tentar processar uma pequena rotina ocorre um erro na seguinte linha:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> OverflowError: int too large to convert to float

Como posso corrigir esse erro?

é possivel trabalhar com números extremamente longos em python?

Comment: Experimenta `math.fsum` para somar.

Comment: Pode adicionar o seu código na pergunta?

Comment: Mas você precisa inteiros ou float? O erro diz que não foi possível converter para float, mas se você precisa de inteiros, nem há porquê fazer essa conversão.

Comment: é uma pergunta bem objetiva, que alguém conhecendo a lignuagem pode responder sem ambiguidades, e sem  exemplos do código usado - é sobre a capacidade da linguagem. Não tem por que ter "downvote" ou querer fechar!

Comment: A pergunta faz referência a um erro de código sem colocar o código. Não me pareceu uma pergunta que tem a ver com a linguagem. me pareceu algo como "eu tentei fazer um código com números grandes e deu erro. eu não sei porque deu erro e estou inferindo que é uma limitação da linguagem".

Comment: "Se for possível, como posso trabalhar com valores inteiro com 1 milhão de dígitos ou mais em python?"  e "é possivel trabalhar com números extremamente longos em python?" - qual é a ambiguidade disso?  Se não sabe, pode simplesmente dar um upvote e espere quem sabe responder - todo mundo se benefícia. Agora se a gente for ficarruminando "talvez eu soubesse arrumar o erro que ele está tendo se pelo menos eu soubesse o que ele tentou fazer - deixa eu puni-lo com donvotes por não ter colocado o código" (o que é pior do que comentar pedindo para colocar código - isso é até ok - mas não downvotes)

Comment: Talvez não tenha entendido meu ponto nessa parte do código. Ele tem a ver com [essa recomendação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) porque eu não vejo como responder "sim, a linguagem trabalha" e explicar vai resolver o erro que ele postou na pergunta.

Comment: Um [exemplo de um inteiro com 1 milhão de dígitos](https://repl.it/@acwoss/ClutteredCarelessCalculator) (sim, pode contar) funcionando. Como pode demorar bastante para rodar, pode ver esse [GIF animado](https://imgur.com/171n0QA).

Answer (score 7):

Sim - é possível - 
Números inteiros em Python não tem limite de tamanho.
Não saberia dizer no entanto se a implementação interna para operações com esses números vai ser eficiente o suficiente para fazer várias operações com esses números.

O erro que você está tendo é que em algum ponto nas suas contas você fez uma operação que resultou num número em ponto flutuante. Em Python 3, uma divisão, por exemplo, faz isso  - Números em ponto flutuante são limitados ao padrão Float 64 ([IEEE 754-2008](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format)), (ou outro tipo, dependendo da arquitetura da CPU).  Esses números vão perder precisão - ou seja, descartar dígitos para qualquer número maior que `2 ** 53` - que correspondem a cerca de 16 dígitos decimais (16, não 16000).

Para "brincar de algumas operações", você certamente pode usar os inteiros nativos de Python - apenas com o cuidado de usa a "divisão inteira", que usa o operador de barra dupla `//`, em vez de `/` que converte o resultado pra float (e, claro, o módulo `%` funciona bem com inteiros grandes).

Se for fazer pesquisas sérias, pode haver alguma biblioteca de inteiros grandes que use a GPU de forma eficiente - e que tenha ligações com Python

(google google)

Aqui -  https://pypi.org/project/gmpy2/  - não usa a GPU, mas usa as bibliotecas de ponta d e precisão arbitrária, com ligação para Python, garantindo que você vai poder usar o máximo de performance da sua CPU e ainda fzer experiências a partir do modo interativo em Python ou no Jupyter notebook.  A única referência a uma biblioteca dessas usando a GPU que achei se chama "gpump", mas não achei nem instruções de como instala-la, muito menos algo sobre poder usa-la a partir de Python (e de qualquer forma, é só para hardware Nvidia).

Abaixo seguem alguns exemplos numa seção interativa do ipython, criando e manipulando um número com 2 milhões de dígitos. (eu uso a extensão `%time` do Ipython para exibir o tempo que o python leva para calcular uma expressão):

```
In [2]: %time a = int('7' * 1_000_000)
CPU times: user 4.5 s, sys: 2.21 ms, total: 4.5 s
Wall time: 4.5 s

In [3]: %time a = int('7' * 2_000_000)
CPU times: user 17.9 s, sys: 10.9 ms, total: 17.9 s
Wall time: 17.9 s

In [4]: b = a // 3

In [5]: %time b = a // 3
CPU times: user 10.7 ms, sys: 979 µs, total: 11.7 ms
Wall time: 11.9 ms

In [6]: %time c = a % 33333333333333333333333333333333333
CPU times: user 19.2 ms, sys: 1.96 ms, total: 21.2 ms
Wall time: 21.3 ms

In [7]: c
Out[7]: 11111888888888888888888888888888888

In [8]: d = a / 4
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OverflowError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-a0e9c689eb57> in <module>()
----> 1 d = a / 4

OverflowError: integer division result too large for a float
```

(Note também , que a partir do Python 3.7 podemos usar `_` como separador de dígitos em números inteiros - aí fica fácil escrever 2 milhões como `2_000_000`)

Também - o tempo para criar e converter um número de 1 milhão de dígitos em string para um inteiro desse tamanho foi de 4.5 segundos - de 2 milhões de dígitos, saltou para 17.9 segundos - o que indica que essa conversão é um algoritmo não linear, e algo como 3 ou 4 milhões de dígitos já pode ser inviável de ser criado dessa forma - mas as operações numéricas com esses números, depois de criados, são bem rápidas.

Acabei instalando a gmpy2 aqui - no Linux pode haver pacotes para a sua distribuição. Como eu uso Python com virtualenv e instalo cada pacote localmente, para instalar no fedora eu precisei installar os pacotes `devel` das bibliotecas binárias que ele usa (No Ubuntu/Debian seriam pacotes `-dev`, instalados como comando `apt`) - esses comandos no shell:

```
sudo dnf install mpfr-devel mpc-devel
pip install gmpy2
```

Se eu fosse instalar no Python do sistema, seria simplesmente: `sudo dnf install python3-gmpy2`. No link acima há as instruções para instalação nos demais sistemas operacionais.

Aqui as operações equivalentes às que fiz com inteiros nativos do Python e seus tempos:

```
In [13]: from gmpy2 import mpz

In [14]: %time a = mpz('7' * 2_000_000)
CPU times: user 111 ms, sys: 7.77 ms, total: 118 ms
Wall time: 119 ms

In [15]: %time b = a // 4
CPU times: user 1.65 ms, sys: 0 ns, total: 1.65 ms
Wall time: 1.69 ms

In [16]: %time c = a % 33333333333333333333333333333333333333333333
CPU times: user 5.24 ms, sys: 54 µs, total: 5.29 ms
Wall time: 5.37 ms

In [17]: d = a / 3333333333333

In [18]: type(d)
Out[18]: mpfr
```

Ou seja: construir um número inteiro a partir de string caiu de 18 segundos para 120 milisegundos - cerca de 100 X mais rápido. E a divisão caiu de 11.9 milisegundos para 1.7 milissegundos - umas 5 vezes mais rápido. Além disso, a gmpy2 inclui também tipos decimais de precisão arbitrária (como o decimal.Decimal do Python) - com conversão automática na divisão - veja  o último exemplo, o tipo numérico passa a ser da classe "mpfr".

PS. Eu usei o google para responder a parte final da pergunta, mas não é uma busca tão trivial - tem que saber o que procurar - de forma alguma quis dizer "você poderia ter usado o Google em vez de perguntar).